# Zoom animation C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, canvas, zooming

I want to add an animation effect to my Wpf project. The animation should be slowly zooming the object in Canvas Panel.

I found a good article on CodeProject website. But it zooms to the upper-left corner. What I want is to zoom to the object or point I desired.

These are the codes below.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/860914/Add-Zooming-to-a-WPF-Window-or-User-Control?msg=5967587#xx5967587xx

```
private void btnAnimate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // We may have already set the LayoutTransform to a ScaleTransform.
    // If not, do so now.

    var scaler = mCanvas.LayoutTransform as ScaleTransform;

    if (scaler == null)
    {
        scaler = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);
        mCanvas.LayoutTransform = scaler;
    }

    // We'll need a DoubleAnimation object to drive
    // the ScaleX and ScaleY properties.

    DoubleAnimation animator = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600)),
    };

    // Toggle the scale between 1.0 and 1.5.

    if (scaler.ScaleX == 1.0)
    {
        animator.To = 1.5;
    }
    else
    {
        animator.To = 1.0;
    }

    scaler.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animator);
    scaler.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, animator);
}
```

Comment: Hint: `ScaleTransform` has properties `CenterX` and `CenterY`. Are you specifying those anywhere?

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried with default values like 'new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0 , 500, 500);'  but the result is same.

Comment: But presumably you're only doing that if `mCanvas.LayoutTransform` isn't already set... if it's been set already, you won't be creating a new ScaleTransform.

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed the if (scaler==null) condition. I made sure to set. Then i tried again but the result is same.